# Pagination issue with distributed system

Tags: java, hibernate, rest, pagination

Exposing REST service which will return paginated list in a descending order by Date using FilterOffset and FilterCount query param values. Let me explain the scenario.

1. If *Client1* asks for **Page 1** (FilterOffset=0, FilterCount=1000).
2. My service selects first 1000 records from DB and returns.
3. Now assume *Client2* updated **#1020**th record, timestamp has been updated to current.
4. *Client1* again asks for **Page 2** (FilterOffset=1001, FilterCount=1000).
5. My service picks the next 1000 records from DB and returns, but this time **#1020**th record not included in the response since it has recently updated so it never be picked from DB.

*Client1* has to request for **Page 1** again to get the recent updated record **#1020**th.

- Do you think this is problem with all distributed systems?
- Is there any way to avoid this?

Answer (score 0):

You say

> My service selects first 1000 records from DB

Remember that this is the first 1000 records... as the DB presents them. The order is unspecified, as per sql specs.

So, with PostgreSQL for instance, you'll get them in the order that they were last altered in the database. That's how PostgreSQL will present the data to you, it's how it will choose what to send you.

You can probably just alter the database query to add ordering by a certain column.

So, just adding `order by <field you want to order by>` should suffice.

Comment: Thank You, we are applying order by clause to UPDATED_DATE, my query picks the most recent updated records from Oracle DB.

Comment: @Lovababu Was your problem not exactly that? As far presenting the data to multiple people, I don't think you can get around that. The data will be presented as it is at the moment it is requested. And if it's altered, then it's altered. You'd have to add some kind of caching mechanism that outputs one specific result for a certain amount of time, no matter what. But doing that for all possible calls is a prohibitive amount of work, both initially and in updating it later.

Comment: Thanks @Koen De Groote, Yes we are applying cache on client side through ETag. So are you agree this kind of issue exist in distributed systems?

Comment: @Lovababu The issue certainly exists. Whether or not it is a **problem** depends on the situation. If the user wants to see "what are the results **right now**", then the changed output is what they want and it is not a problem. If you want to control the output differently, then it is a problem.